# Caching in Node js command line app

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

I'm trying to build a command line app using Node.js

I use [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) for caching some data that comes from API calls.

However when I try to retrieve the data `myCache.get( "key" )` that have been previously set using `myCache.set( "key", data, 10000 );` it is always returning `undefined`.

I guess the issue is when I run the app from the command line I'm creating the cache object every time `const myCache = new NodeCache();`.

But without creating the object, caching won't work obviously. Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache library you are using is keeping the data in the application memory. So once the app exits, the cache is lost.

In the web application the situation is different because the app never exits (unless it crashes), so the cache stays with the data.

One way to solve this is to store the cache in the external storage like `Redis` (but you'll have to have the Redis server running for that) or maybe just in the text file or SQLite db. You need either to write a simple caching library for that or search for a library that provides the persistent storage.

Update: quick search gives this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cache-manager, I didn't use it, but the docs say it supports may different storages to persist the data and `node-cache-manager-fs` might be good for your case.

Comment: Yeah! Guessed that might be the issue. Using Redis would be an overkill though. Need to find out something.

Comment: I updated the answer with the library I got from the quick search, it supports file system as a storage which might fit good your use case.

Comment: Checked that it works fine. Also tried with node_redis - https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis . This one works fine too, doesn't require to run an extra Redis server I guess.

Comment: I think `node_redis` does require an external server. If you have Redis running on your machine it might just pick it up and use it.

Comment: You are right. There was some old Redis server running on my system. I killed it and node_redis threw an error.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
const NodeCache = require("node-cache");
const myCache = new NodeCache();
```

in top of the code

first declare this in top like we declare usually node modules
so it works fine.
we can set,get,delete cache all are works great.
Hope works for you also